# Performance Issue - How to display very large text file in j2me

Tags: performance, text, java-me, midp

I want to display a very large text file but want to break it so that after every 1024 characters shown (page), the user will have to press next to read the next set of characters while back will take them to the exact same previous characters (if any).

Performance wise, am I to create an array of forms and store each 'page' or should the creation of the form be at the point the user presses next or previous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance wise, none of approaches you consider is guaranteed to be problem-free. MIDP 2 specification (JSR-118) does not enforce any specific performance requirements for cases like that. As a result, different devices may behave differently.

- To stay on a safe side, you may implement both approaches and let users choose which one works better on their device.

Another option worth considering is to use uneditable [TextBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextBox.html) instead of Form. *TextBox* primary purpose is to display large chunks of text - because of that one may expect that sensible device manufacturers will provide an implementation optimized for that. *TextBox* even has a method `getMaxSize` which will let you know if device "thinks" that *1024 characters* are too much for it.

Comment: Great! I'll check this and get back to you.

Comment: Eventually I just stuck to just the TextBox. Maybe I'll do the rest based on feedbacks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Performance  wise ?? That would depend on the size no short cut with j2me .... another option is to split the files to smaller chunks.
2. Reading InputStream  ...  Use read with offset and length is more efficient

   ```
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file);
    is.read(b, 0, 1024);
   ```

You can add a comment of you need anything else

Thanks
:)